# Displaying Mobile WordPress in Android

Tags: java, android, wordpress, mobile, adt

I'm currently working on an app for a website/class.  Currently, it pulls the RSS feed of the site, parses it appropriately, and when an item is clicked, it launches a new Activity with a WebView to display the page.

My current problem is that on smaller devices, such as the HTC One or Samsung Stratosphere, it defaults to showing the mobile version of the site.  This is precisely what I want to happen across all devices, but on my Samsung Galaxy Note 8, it defaults to loading the desktop version of the page.

Is anyone familiar with WordPress and Android and can help me force the WebView on the Galaxy (and, therefore, other devices) to load the mobile page by default?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WebSettings` object obtained by the `WebView`'s `getSettings()` Method and change the UserAgent string.

```
WebSetting settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0");
```

For current Firefox 26.0 or browser of your choice. This should force the Website to display in Desktop mode, since this is what the Websites do to determine if they serve a mobile or desktop version.

**Update:** 
You an also force it mobile by using mobile UserAgent. For more information check out this website with example UserAgents.

Some examples for historical references if the link becomes invalid:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; de-ch; HTC Sensation Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

[WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html)

Comment: OP asks how to force open in mobile mode though, not in desktop mode.

Comment: Same way, just use a mobile UserAgent

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer for me!  This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Did it solve your issue? If it did solve, accept the q uestion, so it won't be tracked anymore by the StackOverflow bot and not pushed up anymore and also disappear in the unanswered tab